# Break JENKINS job when it is in pending state

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a JENKINS powershell job that runs SVN CLI commands.Sometime they run for more than 5 minutes and i want to break those builds.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Tried clicking the "Abort" button?

Answer (score 0):

1. As Slav says, click abort
2. Consider running your svn ops from svn plugin..
3. If your svn is the problem, you might want to write a job that takes a job as an arg, finds the slave/node the job is running on, and visits the slave/node to kill the svn transaction with a kill command. Not trivial, sorry.  I assume your svn command is not doing a write operation .. killing svn here could be bad.
4. Try putting your svn jobs in a separate step or job that will allow you to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Build Timeout Plugin is what you are looking for?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin

Note the disclaimer on the wiki page about not being able to abort jobs in certain states.